# How to get response in list form using Unirest?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, httprequest, unirest

My project is written in the Java programming language using the Spring Boot framework.
I use Unirest library for getting requests to some API and I want to get response in forms, which looks like `List<SomeResponse>`
Below I write some example of request, which I try to make.
Why do I need a list? Because this data structure is more convenient and used throughout the rest of the huge project.
  I tried various options for receiving a response to the request, but I could not get the `List <SomeResponse>` in any way. At the moment, my efforts have led me only to the fact that I get an array of the objects I need. Of course, we could try to cast the array to list, but here, as it seems to me, we lose in speed.

```
 try {
            SomeResponse[] SomeResponses = Unirest.post(url)
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .header("Authorization", key)
                    .body("[\"" + address + "\"]")
                    .asObject(SomeResponse[].class)
                    .getBody();
            return Result.ok(SomeResponses);
        } catch (UnirestException e) {
            return Result.error("Error in call API " + url);
        }
```

Also, I have configured the Jackson library, which serializes the JSON format, which  that we receive  in response to a request, in POJO classes. Perhaps you could tell how to configure the mapper correctly so that it can accept and serialize this response.

Few words about versions of libraries and frameworks. I used Gradle to build and manage dependencies.

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.0.0.RELEASE
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.1
com.mashape.unirest:unirest-java:1.4.9
```

Thanks a lot for your answers! 
P.S.
Sorry, this question may have a bad structure, but this is the first time I am writing a problem on this platform, I promise to make my question better in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the `SomeResponse[].class` in `asObject` with a `GenericType<List<SomeResponse>>` object.

```
try {
    List<SomeResponse> someResponses = Unirest.post(url)
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .header("Authorization", key)
        .body("[\"" + address + "\"]")
        .asObject(new GenericType<List<SomeResponse>>() {})
        .getBody();
        return Result.ok(someResponses);
 } catch (UnirestException e) {
     return Result.error("Error in call API " + url);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
After that, how can I convert this List to List<MyClass>?

Comment: I have updated my answer. The trick is to use [GenericType](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.konghq/unirest-java/latest/kong/unirest/GenericType.html)